# Array of object not sorting on a key

Tags: javascript

I have the following array of objects that I want to order by name key. For some reason if I try to sort by the "name" key it doesn't sort. If I sort by a "price_value" key it works  .

```js
let arr = [
  {
    "name": "Road Bike",
    "slug": "road-bike",
    "price_value": 2499
  },
  {
    "name": "Laptop",
    "slug": "laptop",
    "price_value": 1299,
  },

];

let br = [...arr].sort((a, b) => a.name - b.name)[0].name;

console.log(br) //should be Laptop, even if you try to sort on slug key doesn't work
```

I always get Road Bike as first element.
If I try to sort on price_value key it works normally.

```
let br = [...arr].sort( (a,b) => a.price_value - b.price_value )[0].name;
console.log( br ) //It's Laptop as expected
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: You cannot subtract two strings…

Answer (score -1):

You cannot subtract string. `a.name - b.name` is not a valid operation and returns `NaN`.

It should work if you do:

```js
let br = [...arr].sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))[0].name;
```

Comment: let br = [...arr].sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))[0].name;